# Stuck solving an equation using the floor operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, problem-solving, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am not entirely familiar with the equation ninja'ing involving the floor operators. Here is my problem. I need to solve for $x$. **Everything** is an integer, including $x$:

$$
a - 1 = \lfloor {\frac{x - b}{b - c} \rfloor}
$$

The wiki has a nice page on the [floor operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), but I am new at equations involving floor manipulations, so I am not really sure how to go about isolating $x$ at this point, thereby solving for it. Thanks.

EDIT: This is not a homework problem. I am writing software that needs to solve this for a seismological problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a - 1 = \lfloor {\frac{x - b}{b - c} \rfloor}$ if and only if
$a - 1\le \frac{x - b}{b - c}<a $. So you have to solve this system of inequalities.

Comment: Doesn't this mean there are possibly more than one solution to the problem?

Comment: @Spacey Of course, this is possible, there are clearly exactly $|b-c|$ solutions.